# Phonegap: Dynamically show & hide status bar (iOS Xcode)

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, xcode, cordova

I just downloaded Astrid to-do lists from the AppStore and discovered something pretty cool and new to me: a dynamic status bar that is being shown and hidden depending on the user's actions.

For a long time now, I've had an inner battle with myself trying to decide whether or not to display the status bar in some of my apps. This would definitely solve my ambivalence.

What it does, to be more precise, is to always display the status bar unless it's syncing. When this happens, the bar subtly fades out and a loading spinner is displayed along with user feedback. Once done, the status bar fades back again. Very nice and neat way to give user feedback.

Does anyone know how to do this? Putting a transparent layer on top of it which is being lowered in opacity to zero and then back again is probably not possible as i assume the status bar will always hold the greater z-index (to speak in CSS-terms), but how then? I'm using phonegap, cordova for most of my apps so a solution compatible with the PG platform would be preferable.

I first thought of adding print screens to this post to further clarify what I mean, but figured only a video would adequatly do this, so I guess it would be best if you download the app yourselves if unsure of the effect I'm trying to portray here. If you can be bothered with this, just install the Astrid to-do lists app from the appstore and pull down to refresh.

Answer (score 4):

You can dynamically show/hide the status bar with the `UIApplication` class.

From the [UIApplication Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:
>
> Hides or shows the status bar, optionally animating the transition.
>
> ```
> - (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
> ```

So you can turn it on/off at will (and fade in whatever you want instead, as you originally proposed above), with something like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Comment: Still need to know if there's any way this can be done using Phonegap

Comment: Yes, absolutely - you'll leverage phone gap's plugin system: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS